# How to write curl -XGET command in ajax

Tags: ajax, curl

I am running this command (this works):

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:15439/logstash/thresholds
```

And I want to write it in AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:15439/logstash/thresholds",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",  
  success: function(data) {
    var json_response = data;
        console.log("success");
      console.log(data);

  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

But it refuses for:

> "OPTIONS http://localhost:15439/logstash/thresholds
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Any idea why?

When I run `curl -XGET -v http://localhost:15439/logstash/thresholds` I get:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 15439 (#0)
* Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 15439 (#0)
> GET /logstash/thresholds HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:15439 > Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2510
< ETag: W/"H7IFEeDwS43oKpCDN92CPQ=="
< Date: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:32:57 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Add `-v` to see the request and response headers - When you do `curl -XGET -v http://localhost:15439/logstash/thresholds` what are you getting back?  Is the received `Content-Type: application/json`?  What does the outgoing `Accept:` header say?  Is the server-side willing to output `application/json`?

Comment: `* About to connect() to localhost port 15439 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 15439 (#0)
> GET /logstash/thresholds HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:15439
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2510
< ETag: W/"H7IFEeDwS43oKpCDN92CPQ=="
< Date: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 07:32:57 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive`